# Meteor, how to update collection with optimistic UI

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods, optimistic-ui

in my app I placed the methods in a shared location between client and server. this way as suggested in meteor [docs](http://info.meteor.com/blog/optimistic-ui-with-meteor-latency-compensation) the method mechanism takes care of optimistic UI.

but I just read in the David Weldon [blog](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/methods#disqus_thread) about two-tier implementation and it makes lot of sense to me.

question is how can I achieve optimistic UI with two-tier implementation.

1. Move Methods to server, update the clientDB in template events for optimistic UI and deny all the updated from client side to DB.
2. is there any way that methods be available in client side, but only be callable from another method?

any suggested approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the important thing is to deny client-side inserts/updates. Once that is done, then you can run the second tier code from the client, and it won't actually do anything, because it will be denied.

Here are a few paragraphs from https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-pattern-two-tiered-methods/ which support that view:

> Client & Server
>
> Although I stated that the postSubmit function primarily expected to run on the server, it will run on the client in two situations.
>
> First, when called from the postSubmit method as part of that method’s client-side simulation. In that case, Meteor will perform the simulation, insert the post in the client-side database, and then finally trigger the server-side postSubmit method call.
>
> The other use case is when someone calls the postSubmit function from the  browser console directly. If that happens, the Posts.insert() call will fail because we aren’t allowing client-side inserts, and nothing will happen.
>
> Note that allow/deny doesn’t affect code executed from within a Meteor method, which is why simulations don’t fail even if you didn’t declare an allow/deny policy.

So in other words, answer #1: keep the methods in a common location and remove the insecure package (meteor remove insecure)

Answer to #2: It doesn't matter if they are called outside of the method because they will be denied.

Comment: ok what Sacha did is he moved the write to DB method to a server only layer. the client can't access that method and get denies. in the method he checks some condition and if client doesn't have access they get the error right away.  but it is not optimistic UI because the write only takes place in server and client have to wait for a response from server, he tried to speed it up by deferring the callback but still it is not optimistic UI.

Comment: You don't need to do that. The "second tier" function should remain in shared code, so both client and server can access it. If the client calls it via Meteor.call (i.e. a method), then the second tier function is run under meteor's simulation, and the insert will occur on the client data (that's the optimistic UI that you're after). If the server then runs it and it is rejected, then the insert will be rolled-back on the client. If it is run outside of the method call (e.g. via console), then the insert will not be allowed at all (after running "meteor remove insecure")

Comment: but that way The second tier method can get called directlt from client without first methods verification!

Comment: The quote from David Weldon in my answer covers that scenario: "If that happens, the Posts.insert() call will fail because we aren’t allowing client-side inserts, and nothing will happen."

Comment: that is not true! if it is inside of a method allow/ deny doesn't matter. unless it get denied somehow that I don't understand.

Comment: @davidWeldon can you look at this please

Comment: Ah, got it - the second tier isn't inside a method - it has to be outside of a method. Have a read of the article linked above, in particular the section under "The submitPost Function" where he explains the reasons for having a non-method function. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-pattern-two-tiered-methods/